# Is it possible to 'reset' a git branch to an empty state?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-branch

The company I'm at abused Git pretty hard for several years. Development was done on master and a long lived 'release' branch was used for releases. The abuse was that people checked directly into release so much that master could no longer be merged into it, so commits were cherry picked into release adhoc. History between the two is a disaster. We've moved to short lived release branches, our development branch, 'dev', was branched from the old 'release' branch.

I would like to start development on master again but its history contains tons of commits that were not in 'release' and were never tested. I tried several different ways deleting the branch on the remote in a way that no commits from old master on a local dev box could get pushed up to new master. What I want to do (in my magical ideal world) is:

1. Delete master on remote
2. Branch 'dev' to a new master
3. Push new master to remote
4. Have no history from old master be pushed into new master

Having everyone delete master locally and then check it out again is the most straightforward solution but also the hardest to actually do with 30+ developers in multiple countries.

Is there a way on the remote to reject a push if it contains a certain commit, or merges with a commit? I know the last commit on old master that was cherry picked into release, if I can identify pushes that bring in anything older than that they can be rejected. Other than that I'm not sure what other possibilities there are to achieve something like this.

Comment: You can write any server receive hook you want with any logic you want. If you moved master to a separate DAG and then GCed all the old commits I'd think that would be a non-issue though.

Comment: @AndrewC: I think he's worried that someone will re-introduce all the old history by merging a commit from it.  I've seen a similar (but different) problem and we simply hardcoded a particular set of SHA-1s to reject in the pre-receive hook.

Comment: @torek when you hardcoded the SHA-1s in the hook did you have to search the history of the commits being pushed? I considered that but decided search history back a few months on every push was going to kill our server.

Comment: @PatrickAuld: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Using `git rev-list` is easy: on an existing ref *R* being updated from *oldsha* to *newsha* you find new commits in the pre-receive hook with `git rev-list oldsha..newsha`.  That's an easy thing for git to do.  (If you haven't removed existing commits and need to check for merges, add a second rev-list with `--merges` and check all the parent IDs too.)  If someone is creating a *new* ref (so that *oldsha* is 40 `0`s), it's harder, but those tended not to re-pollute the repo, so we didn't bother checking those.